# Programmatically Declare Array of Arbitrary Rank

Tags: c#, arrays

In C#, there are three types of arrays: one-dimensional, jagged, and multi-dimensional rectangular.

The question is: given an array of a specific size, how can we create a new array with the same dimensions and rank?

In the case of a multidimensional rectangular array, there appears to be no syntax by which it is possible to define the size and rank (number of dimensions) at runtime.

C# declares multidimensional arrays with commas in the indexers:

```
object[,,] myArray = new object[2,4,2];
```

In the above example, I can determine the shape of the array by invoking the `Rank` property and the size of each dimension by calling the `GetLength` method and passing the specified dimension.

However, even though I can determine that `myArray` is 2 x 4 x 2, how can I programmatically create a new instance of an array with the same dimensions, **if I am not given the rank of the array beforehand?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`Array.CreateInstance(Type, Int32[])`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dfs8044k.aspx) method to create an array of an arbitrary size.

But the problem, you will have after creating this array is: How do you efficiently access the elements of the array if you don't know its rank?

You may use [myArray.GetValue(Int32[])](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c2cf72s5.aspx) and [myArray.SetValue(Object, Int32[])](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/758awxk7.aspx) but I assume the performance is no that good.

To sum up:

```
public static Array CreateArray(Array array)
{
    // Gets the lengths and lower bounds of the input array
    int[] lowerBounds = new int[array.Rank];
    int[] lengths = new int[array.Rank];
    for (int numDimension = 0; numDimension < array.Rank; numDimension++)
    {
        lowerBounds[numDimension] = array.GetLowerBound(numDimension);
        lengths[numDimension] = array.GetLength(numDimension);
    }

    Type elementType = array.GetType().GetElementType();  // Gets the type of the elements in the input array

    return Array.CreateInstance(elementType, lengths, lowerBounds);    // Returns the new array
}
```

### Update

I've done a little benchmark to compare performance of the array indexer and the GetValue, SetValue versions.

Here is the code I used:

```
const int size = 10000000;
object[] array1 = new object[size];
object[] array2 = new object[size];

Random random;
random = new Random(0);
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    array1[i] = random.Next();
    array2[i] = random.Next();
}

Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

Console.ReadKey();
stopwatch.Restart();
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    array1[i] = array2[i];
stopwatch.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("Indexer method: {0}", stopwatch.Elapsed);

random = new Random(0);
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    array1[i] = random.Next();
    array2[i] = random.Next();
}

Console.ReadKey();
stopwatch.Restart();
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    array1.SetValue(array2.GetValue(i), i);
stopwatch.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("Get/SetValue method: {0}", stopwatch.Elapsed);
```

The result are:

```
Indexer method: 0.014 s
Set/GetValue method: 1.33 s
```

The result are slightly different if I replace the `int` by `object`.

```
Indexer method: 0.05 s
Set/GetValue method: 0.54 s
```

This can be easily explained by the necessary boxing/unboxing when using integer with `Set/GetValue`.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I guess I just didn't search for it using the right terms. I am not so sure about the assumption that `SetValue` and `GetValue` have poor performance, though. I imagine that normal indexing operations are invoking similar methods behind the scenes.

Comment: @Nicholas I've done a little benchmark and the result is quite... obvious (check the post update).

Comment: After reading this i felt the need to check if this compiles:

`int[] myLengthsArray = new int[2] { 2, 2 };
int[,]  array = (int[,]) Array.CreateInstance( typeof(int), myLengthsArray );`

And that does compile, it does defeat the point of the whole thing a bit though

Comment: I am confused. I don't see anything wrong with your benchmark but if you look at lines 705-708 from https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/array.cs it appears @nicholas is correct?

Answer (score 3):

You can use reflection-like methods:

- Create your array instance by calling [`Array.CreateInstance`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dfs8044k.aspx). This will give you an instance of the [`Array` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.aspx).
- Call [`SetValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/758awxk7.aspx) to assign values to your array.
- Use [`GetValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c2cf72s5.aspx) to retrieve any elements of the array.

Answer (score 2):

You can populate an array of lengths (one per rank) based on the existing array, and then use [`Array.CreateInstance(Type, int[])`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dfs8044k.aspx). So:

```
public static Array CreateNewArrayOfSameSize(Array input)
{
    int[] lengths = new int[input.Rank];
    for (int i = 0; i < lengths.Length; i++)
    {
        lengths[i] = input.GetLength(i);
    }
    return Array.CreateInstance(array.GetType().GetElementType(), lengths);
}
```

It's a shame there isn't a method to return all the lengths in one go, but I can't see one. Also I'm surprised that there isn't an `ElementType` property on `Array`, but again it may just be eluding me.

Note that this *doesn't* attempt to maintain the same upper/lower bounds for each dimension as the original array - just the sizes.