# How to get cross section of 3 dimensional array c#

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

Say you have a 3-dimensional array in c#

```
int space[width, height, depth];
```

And you would like to implement the method

```
public int[,] GetCrossSection(int position, int dimension)
```

Where 'position' is the point along the 'dimension' specified where you would like to extract your slice. It is important to **not** use the fact that we are only dealing with 3 dimensions, in the examples below you could fix them by adding if statements and assume the matrix will not grow beyond 3 dimensions.

My first attempt (commented problem areas):

```
public int[,] GetCrossSection(int position, int dimension)
{
    int[] dimensionIterationInterval = new int[] { width, height, depth };
    var dims = new List<int>(dimensionIterationInterval);
    dims.RemoveAt(dimension);
    dimensionIterationInterval = dims.ToArray();


    int[,] crossSection = new int[dimensionIterationInterval[0], dimensionIterationInterval[1]];
    int[] itr = new int[2];
    for (itr[0] = 0; itr[0] < dimensionIterationInterval[0]; itr[0]++)
    {
        for (itr[1] = 0; itr[1] < dimensionIterationInterval[1]; itr[1]++)
        {
           crossSection[itr[0], itr[1]] = space[?,?,?]; //Problem
        }
     }
}
```

And my second attempt, equally futile:

```
public int[,] GetCrossSection(int position, int dimension)
{
    int[,] dimensionIterationInterval = new int[,] { { 0, width }, { 0, height }, { 0, depth } };
    dimensionIterationInterval[dimension, 0] = position;
    dimensionIterationInterval[dimension, 1] = position + 1;

    int[,] crossSection = new int[?,?]; //Problem
    for (int x = dimensionIterationInterval[0, 0]; x < dimensionIterationInterval[0, 1]; x++)
     {
       for (int y = dimensionIterationInterval[1, 0]; y< dimensionIterationInterval[1, 1]; y++)
        {
          for (int z = dimensionIterationInterval[2, 0]; z < dimensionIterationInterval[2, 1]; z++)
          {
              crossSection[?, ?] = space[x, y, z]; // Problem
          }
         }
      }
 }
```

Both those attemps run into dead ends. How would you solve it? It's ok to have the fixed iteration loops for the number of dimensions of space[,,]. If the number of dimensions grow that is somewhat managable. Clever/limited if statments could work, but not excessive ifs for each dimension.

Comment: Clever language specific things appreciated, but I'm also interested in the problem in a 'pseudo-codey' sort of way, if there is some structure you can use to get around the problems i found in my two attempts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some weeks of doing other things and after messing around with Mykola's answer a bit I arrived at:

```
int[,] GetSlice(int[,,] source /*non dynamic 1*/, int dimension, int position)
{
    int dimensions = source.Rank; 
    int[] dims = new int[dimensions-1];

    for(int j = 0; j < dims.Length; j++){
        dims[j] = source.GetLength(j + (j >= dimension ? 1 :0));
    }

    var result = new int[dims[0], dims[1]]; // non dynamic 2

    int[] start = new int[dimensions];
    int[] end = new int[dimensions];
    for(int i = 0; i < dimensions; i++){
        start[i] = dimension == i ? position : 0;
        end[i] = dimension == i ? position + 1 : source.GetLength(i);
    }

    int[] counters = new int[dimensions];
    for (counters[0] = start[0]; counters[0] < end[0]; counters[0]++)
    for (counters[1] = start[1]; counters[1] < end[1]; counters[1]++)
    for (counters[2] = start[2]; counters[2] < end[2]; counters[2]++) // non dynamic 3
    {
        int[] sliceCoord = new int[dimensions-1];

        for(int i = 0; i < t.Length; i++){
            sliceCoord[i] = counters[i + (i >= dimension ? 1 :0)];
        }

        result[sliceCoord[0], sliceCoord[1]] = source[counters[0], counters[1], counters[2]]; // non dynamic 4
    }

    return result;
}
```

**Conclusion:** Arrays are not the data structure to do this in if you wan't that kind of dynamic behavior.

The above code was somewhat along the lines I was imagining of when i wrote the question. And still if you want to increase the number of dimensions you have to make changes to 4 places. Currently there is no way to do this cleanly with arrays.

**Update**: It seems you can generalize the code further as you can create an array of dynamic rank. [Programatically Declare Array of Arbitrary Rank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17820509/programatically-declare-array-of-arbitrary-rank) However this seem to come at a performance loss, which most likely is unacceptable

Similar question for reference: [How to get a dimension (slice) from a multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4801990/how-to-get-a-dimension-slice-from-a-multidimensional-array)

Answer (score 2):

Quick draft:

```
    static int[,] GetSlice(int[,,] source, int dimension, int position)
    {
        int l1 = 0, l2 = 0;
        if (dimension == 0)
        {
            l1 = source.GetLength(1);
            l2 = source.GetLength(2);
        }
        else if (dimension == 1)
        {
            l1 = source.GetLength(0);
            l2 = source.GetLength(2);
        }
        else if (dimension == 2)
        {
            l1 = source.GetLength(0);
            l2 = source.GetLength(1);
        }

        var result = new int[l1, l2];

        var s0 = dimension == 0 ? position : 0;
        var s1 = dimension == 1 ? position : 0;
        var s2 = dimension == 2 ? position : 0;

        var m0 = dimension == 0 ? position + 1 : source.GetLength(0);
        var m1 = dimension == 1 ? position + 1 : source.GetLength(1);
        var m2 = dimension == 2 ? position + 1 : source.GetLength(2);

        for (var i0 = s0; i0 < m0; i0++)
        for (var i1 = s1; i1 < m1; i1++)
        for (var i2 = s2; i2 < m2; i2++)
        {
            int x = 0, y = 0;
            if (dimension == 0)
            {
                x = i1;
                y = i2;
            }
            else if (dimension == 1)
            {
                x = i0;
                y = i2;
            }
            else if (dimension == 2)
            {
                x = i0;
                y = i1;
            }

            result[x, y] = source[i0, i1, i2];
        }

        return result;
    }
```

It can be generalised to any number of dimensions (and it even will make code smaller and simpler).

Answer (score 1):

Didn't debug it, but guess it should work

```
 private int[,,] _space = new int[width, height, depth];

    public int[,] GetCrossSection(int position, int dimension)
    {
        if (dimension < 0 || dimension > 2) return null;
        if (position > _space.GetLength(dimension) || position < 0) return null;
        var minMax = new Tuple<int, int>[3];
        var resultXLength = -1;
        var resultYLength = -1;
        for (var i = 0; i < _space.Rank; i++)
        {
            if (i == dimension)
            {
                minMax[i] = new Tuple<int, int>(position, position+1);
            }
            else
            {
                minMax[i] = new Tuple<int, int>(0,_space.GetLength(i));
                if (resultXLength == -1) resultXLength = _space.GetLength(i);
                else resultYLength = _space.GetLength(i);
            }
        }
        var result = new int[resultXLength, resultYLength];
        for (var i = minMax[0].Item1; i < minMax[0].Item2; i++)
            for (var j = minMax[1].Item1; j < minMax[1].Item2; j++)
                for (var k = minMax[2].Item1; k < minMax[2].Item2; k++)
                {
                    switch (dimension)
                    {
                        case 0:
                        {
                            result[j, k] = _space[i, j, k];
                            break;
                        }
                        case 1:
                        {
                            result[i, k] = _space[i, j, k];
                            break;
                        }
                        case 2:
                        {
                            result[i, j] = _space[i, j, k];
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
        return result;
    }
```